# I get a two-dimensional array but can't use it in shell

Tags: shell, jq

```
VALUES=$(cat $JSON_FILE | jq '.["resources"] | map([.name,.type,.url])|.array')
```

I want to range this VALUES . but it may like a string not two dimensional array.

```
echo VALUES is [ [ "br_wind_rain_tex_png", "image", "assets/language/zh-cn/bloodriver/gamescene/effect/xiayu/br_wind_rain_tex.png" ], [ "baccarat_goodWayListItemBg_png", "image", "assets/language/zh-cn/baccarat/game/baccarat_goodWayListItemBg.png" ] ]

#!/bin/bash
BASE_PATH="/Users/likun/source/data/ky_qipai/client/egret"
JSON_FILE=$BASE_PATH/resource/default_zh_cn.res.json
KEYS=$(cat $JSON_FILE | jq '.["groups"]|map(select(.name=="logo"))|.[0]|.keys|split(",")')
#echo $KEYS
VALUES=$(cat $JSON_FILE | jq '.["resources"] | map([.name,.type,.url])|.array')
echo $VALUES
for v in $VALUES
do
echo $v
for vv in $v
do
    if [[ "$vv" == "image" ]]
    then
        echo $vv
    fi
done
break
done
```

Comment: Not sure to fully understand the question, but if you're trying to use a two dimensional array with Bash, it won't work. Bash does NOT support multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If, as seems to be the case from your script, you want to iterate through all the scalar values using a script's `for` loop, you could use the following model:

```
#!/bin/bash

JSON='[ [ "br_wind_rain_tex_png", "image", "assets/language/zh-cn/bloodriver/gamescene/effect/xiayu/br_wind_rain_tex.png" ],
        [ "baccarat_goodWayListItemBg_png", "image", "assets/language/zh-cn/baccarat/game/baccarat_goodWayListItemBg.png" ] ]'

jq '.. | scalars' <<< "$JSON" | while read -r value
do
    echo "$value"
done
```

Since you have not indicated what you are attempting to achieve, let me point out that you might be able to avoid the shell loop entirely, that is, use jq to perform whatever computations are needed on the scalar values.